# How to use dynamic variable (variable.variable.variable) in jinja2 with django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, jinja2

"I want to display a name instead of an ID in my template.

I am using jinja2 and django2.2.1 with python3. I want to use a dynamic variable in my template. I have a dictionary of id and name and I want to display name of related ID in my template view.

```
    name_dict = {
    1 : 'name 1'
    2 : 'name 2'
    }

return name_dict
```

"In my template, I have another object which is `table_data`,
Now in my view, I want to do Like This"

```
  table_data = object with another table data

    {% for data in table_data %}

#This does not gives any error but not printing name

        name_dict.data.id  

#It gives an error

        name_dict[data.id] 

    {% endfor %}
```

"What should I do to display name which is in 'name_dict' "

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you definitely using Jinja2 rather than Django template language?

Comment: Yes, This is my settings.py
'code'
 {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(project_root, 'apps', 'admin', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'environment': 'apps.admin.jinja2.environment',
        },
    },
'code'

Comment: Then show what error you got. That is valid code in Jinja2.

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/key_mapping/list

'Could not parse the remainder: '[data.id]' from 'name_dict[data.id]''

Comment: Well, as I say, that is a Django template language error. So you are not using Jinja2. I don't know where that setting is but it is clearly not taking effect or being overridden.

Comment: I also sent template settings in the second comment. I will check and update you.  Thanks @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yes, you were right @DanielRoseman I just changed my settings and now It is working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you could send the dict key, or value or both to your template from inside of your views.py
like this:

dict ={
'First' : 'aa',
'Second' : 'bb',
}

def myview(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', dict)

and inside of home.html you could work with dict data like this:(consider as jinja code ) 
{% if First %}
{% for string in First %}
.....
remember that you could send a list in place of 'aa' for e.g.